# Demo store banner not disappearing in magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

The demo store notice is not disappearing in Magento. I checked the no option in Display Demo store notice. I even cleared the cache but still, the banner is not removed in the front end. I have attached pictures.

[image: Banner not disappearing in front end]

[image: Chose the no option in backen]

Answer (score 0):

Do a static file deployment again and recheck

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Did the same. Still getting the banner

Comment: Then it should be in the template file. Do an all project search by that text and get where is it.

Comment: Found the template file and removed it. Now it is working perfectly.

Comment: wow its great mate

Answer (score 0):

It should be in the template file. Do an all project search by that text and get where is it.